# MacOSX: avoid hang when getting current directory of Finder via AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, finder

Currently I am using this AppleScript to get the current directory of Finder:

```
tell application "Finder"
    return POSIX path of ((folder of the front window) as text)
end tell
```

When you run this quite often, e.g. put it into a file and run `while true; do sleep 1; osascript -ss myscript; done`, you will see that each time, Finder hangs a bit.

How can I avoid the hanging? Is there any other way to get that information?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really. Applescript isn't known for its speed, and you are, essentially, asking the Finder to recalculate something it may not keep track of as a matter of course.

If you are asking the Finder repeatedly to find this piece of information, then you might want to reconsider your approach. For example, you don't need to have a Finder window open to perform actions on a targeted set of files.

Comment: What does it need to recalculate? I'm quite sure that it must be able to say pretty fast in what directory it is right now. I also don't want to do any actions on a targeted set of files -- I really just want to know about the foreground Finder window, what directory it is showing right now. Also, I don't really care if this is not possible in a fast way with AppleScript. I am asking for *any* way.

Comment: I'm saying it *may* have to calculate it every time, but we'll never really know. Ultimately, you are still held back by Applescript's framework. Applescript doesn't call to the Finder directly; there is a very roundabout path from the code you have written to the application and back, much more than what a comment would allow for explanation.